Installed a universal ceiling fan light on Altura II ceiling fan. Lights flash brightly on then dim as soon as the fan engages
My older home (1995) came with a Home Decorators Collection Altura II ceiling fan which is controlled by a switch on the wall, on and off only. The fan did not come with any lighting so I installed the universal Gazelle Ceiling Fan Light Kit from Hampton Bay. Installation was easy but when the wall switch is turned on the lights will come on for about 2 seconds until the fan engages and then the lights will dim to an unusable brightness. The fan has a reverse module installed: https://www.amazon.com/Anderic-Replacement-Reverse-Module-Ceiling/dp/B0BVBZ3MMB. I have seen newer Altura fans come with a remote receiver: https://www.anderic.com/products/mr77a-rr7222t434-replacement-ceiling-fan-remote-and-receiver-kit-for-home-decorators-collection-altura-68-inch-ceiling-fans.
I am trying to figure out if installing the remote receiver will solve my problem or if it may be an issue with power supply.
Also interested in finding a way to use the light and turn the fan off. Presumably the remote may also provide a solution here. The fan itself does not have its own pull cord to change speeds or turn it on and off. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

If you incorrectly wire a ceiling fan and a light fixture by putting the fan in series with the light, then the light will come on bright until the fan gets going, at which time the light will become unusably dim.
Fan and light must be wired in parallel.
Turn off the power, go back to the wiring diagram that came with the equipment and correct your connections. If it looks right to you, get another set of eyes on it or edit your question by adding a clear, closeup, well-lighted photo of your wiring.
To add a photo, click EDIT then use the sun and mountains icon.

The installation of the universal light kit was just a plug and play kit that required the joining of wiring harness clip to another inside the fan. Both the fan and lighting kit are from Hampton Bay. It sounds like I may need to hire a professional to open up the wall panel to do some wiring work.
